Unexpected behavior of setTimeout/setInterval when tab is inactive
I've implemented a user activity tracking and countdown timer in React using setTimeout and setInterval. Everything works fine when the browser tab is active, but I'm facing issues when the tab is inactive or the browser window is minimized.
The Problem
The timers are supposed to track user inactivity and start a countdown that eventually logs the user out. When I stay on the same tab, the logic works perfectly. However, if I switch to another tab or minimize the browser, the timers seem to slow down or pause, and they don’t resume correctly when I return to the tab. For example, a countdown that should have finished while the tab was inactive instead starts only when I come back to the tab.
Example code
export const useActivityTimer = ({
  inactivityTimeout,
}: useActivityTrackerProps) => {
  const [isUserInactive, setIsUserInactive] = useState(false)
  const [isTimerClear, setIsTimerClear] = useState(false)
  const inactivityTimerRef = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | null>(null)
  const resetInactivityTimerRef = useRef<() => void>()

  const resetInactivityTimer = useCallback(() => {
...
    inactivityTimerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsUserInactive(true)
    }, inactivityTimeout * ONE_SECOND_IN_MS)
  }, [inactivityTimeout, isTimerClear, isUserInactive])

  const clearActivityTimer = useCallback(() => {
    setIsTimerClear(true)
    if (inactivityTimerRef.current) {
      clearTimeout(inactivityTimerRef.current)
    }
  }, [])

  const handleActivity = useCallback(() => {
    if (resetInactivityTimerRef.current) {
      resetInactivityTimerRef.current()
    }
  }, [])

  const addEventListeners = useCallback(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleActivity)
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleActivity)
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleActivity)
  }, [handleActivity])

  const removeEventListeners = useCallback(() => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', handleActivity)
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleActivity)
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleActivity)
  }, [handleActivity])

  useEffect(() => {
    resetInactivityTimerRef.current = resetInactivityTimer
    resetInactivityTimerRef.current()
  }, [resetInactivityTimer])

  useEffect(() => {
...
  }, [addEventListeners, inactivityTimeout, removeEventListeners])

  return {
...
  }
}

export const useCountdownTimer = ({
  countdownTime,
}: useCountdownTimerProps) => {
  const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(countdownTime)
  const [isTimeout, setIsTimeout] = useState(false)
  const countdownTimerRef = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setInterval> | null>(null)

  const clearCountdownTimer = useCallback(() => {
...
  }, [])

  const handleTimeout = useCallback(() => {
...
  }, [clearCountdownTimer])

  const startCountdown = useCallback(() => {
    setCountdown(countdownTime)
    countdownTimerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCountdown((prev) => {
        if (prev === 0) {
          handleTimeout()
          return 0
        }
        return prev - 1
      })
    }, ONE_SECOND_IN_MS)
  }, [countdownTime, handleTimeout])

  return {
...
  }
}


Question
Why do setTimeout and setInterval behave differently when the tab is inactive? How can I ensure that the timers work consistently, even when the user is not on the active tab or when the browser is minimized?
